# Problem in units

Tags: units

My goal is to make metric system adjust to my zoom of the scene automatically, as i've seen in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdXzw225KVU 02:30 . But this does not work for me and i get this:

[image: Whhat's that?]

What's that?:)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, could you please edit your question and provide more information about what you trying to achieve and what videos you've watched?

Comment: I have no clue, never seen that before, looks like you are out of range and that is an exponential factor. Try zoomin far in or out, see if it changes

Comment: Nope, zoomin far in or out doesn't change anything